# How to mock WepAPi response (JSON) in client MVC client project

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, mocking, tdd, moq

I want to test my service proxy class that is calling a MVC WebApi and gets back a JSON response.

```
public class CarServiceProxy
{

public CarsCollection GetCars()
    {
        CarsCollection cars = new CarsCollection();

        string api = "api/Car/GetCars";

        var response = httpClient.GetAsync(api).Result;

        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            cars = response.Content.ReadAsAsync<CarsCollection >().Result;
        }

        return cars;
    }
}
```

then my MVC WebSite controller class calls the above proxy class as:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    CarsCollection cars = this.carsServiceProxy.GetCars();
    return View(cars);
}
```

Now to test both in isolation, I can test my controller using MOQ and mocking carServiceProxy and faking the CarsCollection with some fake data in my tests. I am ok so far.

But, how do I test the proxy class using MOQ to mock the API response (JSON)? I think I do need to test because the conversion form JSON to C# happens in that class, and if some one changes my model CarsCollection, that might break. So I do need to test the proxy class.

Answer (score 1):

You will want to create a "Fake" HTTP handler for your client.  This way you can control exactly what HTTP response is returned.  You can inject an HTTP handler when you construct an HTTP client.

For testing I typically use an internal constructor for testing, which accepts an HTTP handler.  This way I can easily test my class that consumes an HTTP Client with a fake handler.  If you take this approach and your unit tests are in a separate assembly, you'll need to add the following to the AssemblyInfo.cs for your target project:

```
[assembly: InternalsVisibleTo("NameSpace.MyUnitTestProject")]
```

Fake Handler:

```
public class FakeHttpMessageHandler : HttpMessageHandler
{
    private HttpResponseMessage _response;

    public FakeHttpMessageHandler(HttpResponseMessage response)
    {
        _response = response;
    }

    protected override Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var responseTask = new TaskCompletionSource<HttpResponseMessage>();
        responseTask.SetResult(_response);

        return responseTask.Task;
    }
}
```

And then to consume (may want to use JSON serialisation helpers here):

```
var response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
response.Content = new StringContent(@"{'Cars':[{'Name':'BMW'}]");
var handler = new FakeHttpMessageHandler(response);
var client = new HttpClient(handler);

// client.GetAsync().result will return the response
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change the httpClient.GetAsync(api).Result part to be moackable and testable to test the proxy class. In other words, you can make your code independent of HTTP request response and just work on JSON data for testing.

Comment: does that mean I'll have to manually provide JSON response for each proxy method to each proxy test? Do you have any example?

Comment: Yes, you will need to provide JSON response to test for each proxy method as this is what you want to test ["I think I do need to test because the conversion form JSON to C# happens in that class..."] which is fair as your code depends on correct conversion from JSON to Cars objects for test completion. As for examples, the code from @mixja above is a good starting point.